# symbolic computation

Tags: c++, math

Does anyone know a good approach/libs for doing algebraic computations in C++?

I have an application being developed in c++ which needs to do algebraic computation. For now I built a C++ parser that accepts expressions in form of strings like "5 + (2 - MYFUNC(3))" which get tokenized into structs and then converted into postfix notation using the Shunting Yard algorithm and evaluated.

The MYFUNC in these expression are my own defined functions that may do some complex computations.

This is a high performance app, the expressions also have variables that are dynamically replaced with values and the expression is re-evaluated

e.g. var1 + (2 - MYFUNC(var2)) -> with var1 and var2 replaced by some values during the course of the run and re-evaluated

I'm  using Linux and so far found [Giac library](http://bernard.parisse.pagesperso-orange.fr/english.html) but not sure if it's good, any feedback would be welcome.

How do people generally approach this problem? The main language in this case is C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on Bison and Flex Parser. The basic idea here is that a grammar file would be written and converted into C code which can be integrated into you application. Any book on Flex and Bison (http://www.amazon.com/Flex-Bison-Text-Processing-Tools/dp/0596155972) is good enough for initial reading.

May be this helps you.!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I was already on a similar path of looking into Boost::Spirit to create a DSL for this but felt it was becoming overkill. It does sound from comments so far that compiled C function would be a very performant solution. Just need to find the right tools.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the fastest way to handle this is to generate a compiled, optimized function at runtime for the defined function, and evaluate it for the different variable values that you may have.  You can do this with [LLVM](http://llvm.org), probably other tools.

Comment: Would this be similar to how regex can do compiled expressions for optimization?

Comment: There's some similarity, but as I understand it, regex's are compiled down to a table which is quicker to evaluate.  With LLVM you'd be compiling down to machine code, you'll get back a function pointer to call.  You can build a function for each set of variable values, or more likely, pass them as a parameter to this function.

Comment: But since both the main C++ program and the LLVM function will be compiled there won't really be any difference in performance. The algebraic string will be parsed and evaluated in the same way in both cases, no?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, so I'll say this.  The performance should be close to the speed of a compiled C++ function which implements your algebraic function.  Except of course, you can vary the function at runtime.  Compiling at runtime will have a penalty but this is negligible if it is amortized over many executions of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a recursive descent parser for the language, because the syntax doesn't look very complex. The parsing may be a tiny bit slower than that of say Flex/Bison, but I'm guessing the parsing will be the least computationally expensive in your project.